# Choosing between probability distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Lets say we know the probability distributions for two events, which have an outcome we want to maximize or minimize. Is there any systematic way of comparing the two distributions so as to say that one is objectively better than the other one in relation to the outcome?

For example, in a trivial case in which we have 2 normal distributions with same skewness variance and kurtosis but different means. In order to choose we just have to compare the two means. But if the probability distributions of the two are too different or are of different types it gets harder to say which one is more appropriate.

If for example, I have an asymmetrical normal distribution with negative skewness, and the same distribution but mirrored horizontally. If I keep moving one of the distributions along the x axis it gets to a point were it is clear which one is better, and there is also a point when both are of almost the same value.

Those cases are easier to solve, but what happens when one is a normal distribution and the other one is a Poisson distribution? does the comparison makes sense when talking about different distributions? is there a systematic and quantifiable approach to this problem?

Comment: Which one is "better" depends on what your objective is.  For instance, is your aim to maximize the mean? Minimize the variance?  Are there any constraints your class of distributions must obey?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the concept of [stochastic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering)?

Comment: I'm still researching about this, is an extremely interesting topic. @Golden_Ratio was right in that it depends on the objective you want to achieve. Also Raskolnikov mentioning stochastic dominance was quite useful. Usually when one distribution stochastically dominates other, that one is the best choice, but the question arises when there is no obvious dominance. The question I guess is, if we don't know the utility function, or rather what objective is being pursued, and neither distribution dominates another, is there a way to choose between them that is optimal?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [article](https://www.rieb.kobe-u.ac.jp/academic/ra/dp/English/DP2014-23.pdf) by Takashi Kamihigashi about partial stochastic dominance, in it he describes a measure of PSD as:

$$
\sigma(F, G) = 1 - \sup_x \{G(x) - F(x)\}
$$

Where $G(x)$ and $F(x)$ are CDFs. The way I understood this is that the maximum difference between the CDFs of 2 distributions evaluated at some point gives the degree of dominance of one over the other.

I implemented in python a function that takes two lists and uses kernel density estimation (I used the same bandwidth for both distributions) to generate two continuous distributions (estimated) for the two samples, it then calculates the CDF for each one, and iterates through the values to search for the maximum difference.

At first it seemed to work ok, but the problem is that it only takes into account the maximum difference, not the minimum difference. So I modified it so that the dominance measure of the first sample into the other one was the addition of the maximum and minimum differences from the CDFs.

The final function seems to give more or less consistent results, but I'm not sure if it's a good measure, or if I implemented it right. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

def getPartialDominance_Values1(values1,values2,plot_CDF=False,plot_KDE=False):
    xEcdf1 =  sorted(values1[:])
    #yEcdf1 = [i/(len(xEcdf1)) for i in range(len(xEcdf1))]

    xEcdf2 =  sorted(values2[:])
    #yEcdf2 = [i/(len(xEcdf2)) for i in range(len(xEcdf2))]

    kde1 = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(xEcdf1)
    kde1.fit()  
    bw1 = 0.8*kde1.bw

    kde2 = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(xEcdf2)
    kde2.fit()  
    bw2 = 0.8*kde2.bw

    finalBandWidth = (bw1+bw2)/2
    kde1.fit(bw=finalBandWidth)  
    kde2.fit(bw=finalBandWidth)  

    rangeMin = min(min(kde1.support),min(kde2.support))
    rangeMax = max(max(kde1.support),max(kde2.support))
   
    precision = 1
    iterations = round((rangeMax-rangeMin)*precision)

    if True:
        yValues_CDF_KDE_1 = []
        yValues_CDF_KDE_2 = []
        acum1 = 0 
        acum2 = 0
        maxDifference = 0
        minDifference = 1
        stepStart = 0.000001
        stepEnd = 1-stepStart
        xValues = []
        for i in range(iterations):
            pos_X = (i/precision)+rangeMin
            acum1+=kde1.evaluate(pos_X)[0]/precision
            acum2+=kde2.evaluate(pos_X)[0]/precision
            
            diff = acum2-acum1
            if (maxDifference<diff):
                maxDifference = diff
            if (diff<minDifference):
                minDifference = diff
            if stepStart<acum1 and stepStart<acum2:
                yValues_CDF_KDE_1.append(acum1)
                yValues_CDF_KDE_2.append(acum2)
                xValues.append(pos_X)
            
            if (stepEnd)<acum1 and (stepEnd<acum2):
                break


    decisionValue = maxDifference+minDifference
    if plot_KDE:          
        plt.plot(kde1.support,kde1.density, 'y-')
        plt.plot(kde2.support,kde2.density, 'r-')
        plt.show()
    if plot_CDF:
        plt.plot(xValues,yValues_CDF_KDE_1, 'y-')
        plt.plot(xValues,yValues_CDF_KDE_2, 'r-')
        plt.show()
    
    print(decisionValue)
    return decisionValue
   

getPartialDominance_Values1([(i**2) for i in range(200)],[(i**2)+0.01 for i in range(200)],True)
getPartialDominance_Values1([100,120,90],[41,43,266],True)
```

[image: Image description]

*CDFs after kernel density estimation for samples $[100, 120, 90]$ (yellow) and $[41,43, 266]$ (red)*

For the first group of samples the Kamihigashi method  correctly detected a stochastic dominance of the second one with respect to the first one. My method of adding the differences gave me a negative value, indicating also that the second sample is more dominant.

For the second group of samples it gives a value of $0.048795$, which indicates that the first one ($[100,120,90]$ in yellow) is slightly closer to stochastic dominance than the second one ($[41,43,266]$ in red). Which is interesting, given that the average value of the first sample is lower than that of the second one. If I make the values even greater in the second sample it starts giving negative values, which indicate that the second one is more partially dominant in that case.

Nonetheless, I'm not sure if this procedure has any flaws, or if it is a wrong interpretation of the method given by Kamihigashi, which from my point of view, might give biased results that don't take into account the full distribution. I could calculate the areas between the CDFs, and add them together with sign varied according to the bigger distribution for that area, but it feels very similar to just calculating the average of the two samples.